# Ошибка в извлечении XML с помощью Ajax

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

В консоли ошибок js никаких нет, но браузер выдает

> `Ошибка Ajax: данные не получены`

```
<!-- xmlget.html -->
<html>

<head>
    <title>Пример извлечения XML с помощью Ajax</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center />
    <h1>Загрузка XML-содержимого в контейнер DIV</h1>
    <div id="info">Это предложение будет заменено</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxRequest() {
        var r;
        try // Для всех браузеров, кроме ие
        {
            r = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            try // ие6+
            {
                r = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try // ie5
                {
                    r = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) // Браузер не поддерживает Ajax
                {
                    r = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    var nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
    url = "rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories";
    var request = ajaxRequest();
    if (request) {
        request.open("GET", "xmlget.php?url=" + url + nocache, true)
        out = "";

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    if (this.responseXML != null) {
                        titles = this.responseXML.getElementByTagName('title')
                        for (j = 0; j < titles.length; ++j) {
                            out += titles[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '<br />'
                        }
                        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = out;

                    } else alert("Ошибка Ajax: Данные не получены")
                } else alert("Ошибка Ajax: " + this.statusText)
            }
        }
        request.send(null)
    } else {
        alert("Ошибка: Ваш браузер не поддерживает AJAX")
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

пхп-файл

```
<?php //xmlget.php
function SanitazeString($var)
{
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    return stripslashes($var);
}

if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo file_get_contents("http://" . SanitazeString($_GET['url']));
}
?>
```

что тут неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

А если напрямую запустить в браузере скрипт xmlget.php - какой результат?

Сдается мне, что просто сервер не дает ответ. xmlget.php -  это ваш PHP скрипт, задача которого получить запрос - обработать и выдать результат в виде xml данных. Вот для того, чтоб проверить, надо запустить этот скрипт не через AJAX запрос, а напрямую в браузере с указанием необходимых GET параметров.

И не работает, на первый взгляд, скорее всего, вот эта функция `file_get_contents` - ее очень часто запрещают на хостингах для получения контента с другого сайта.

На картинке следующая ошибка - вы пытаетесь отправить клиенту заголовок после того как уже отправили тело ответа. см функцию header(). Вы весь код файла xmlget.php привели? Подскажите еще кодировку файла

Comment: А зачем пхп-файл запускать? Он же не для этого, запускать тут надо xmlget.html. ну, если xmlget.php в браузере запустить, то ничего не будет, пустая страница.

Comment: Как тут вообще можно выловить, где ошибка? Я только начинаю это всё изучать.

Comment: Добавьте в php файл, в начало 

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Введите в браузере строку:

    xmlget.php?url=rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories

наблюдайте ошибки.
Скорее всего и правда в php.ini переменная allow_url_fopen установлена в ``Off``. установите ее в ``On``.

Comment: Функция file_get_contents работает, я уже использовала её в другом коде. Есди добавить в начало кода error_reporting(E_ALL); в файле xmlget.php, то браузер никаких ошибок не введет, белый экран. Если ввести в адресную строку браузера http://mysite/xmlget.php?url=rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories, то будет то, что на картинке
<img src="http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/75048610.png" />

Comment: А, нет, вообще будет ошибка в xmlget.php, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in G:\Server\domains\mysite\www\xmlget.php on line 2, вторая строка это как раз строка где error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: кроме ошибки

    titles = this.responseXML.getElementByTagName('title')

надо:

    titles = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('title')

ошибок больше нет. у меня отработали ваши файлы без ошибок.

ЗЫ ``Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`` - ищите ошибку выше (в первой строке), кавычка там видимо затесалась лишняя...